# Finding peaks of signals are not correct

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have the following image:

[image]

I'm getting the envelope using hilbert transform and I'm trying to find the peaks.

Using the following code I get the following wrong peak detection.

Basically I'm trying to segment the letters based on the envelope and the peaks... but I get wrong peaks at the momement.

[image]

```
def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm == 0:
        return v
    return v / norm


'''
reduces the photo to a vector representing its pixel freuqeuncy at each column 
'''


def image_reduce(img):
    col_counts = cv2.reduce(img, 0, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)
    column = col_counts.flatten().tolist()
    # print("Column counts:\n\n", column)
    return column

def slice_digits(image_name):
    img = cv2.imread(image_name, 0)

    column_frequency = image_reduce(cv2.bitwise_not(img))
    column_frequency = normalize(column_frequency)

    env = np.abs(sigtool.hilbert(column_frequency))
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(env > 0.1, height= 0.51)
    plt.plot(env)
    plt.scatter(peaks, env[peaks],  s=50, c='r')

    all_slices = []
    for i in range(len(peaks) - 1):
        x0, x1 = peaks[i:i + 2]
        image_slice = img[:, x0:x1]

        print("coords:", x0, x1)
        # Now do something with the slice, e.g.
        all_slices.append(image_slice)
        plt.figure("Slice %d)" % i)
        plt.imshow(image_slice)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = r"c:\ahmed\doc.png"
    res_image = slice_digits(image)
```

Comment: As-salaamu 'alaikum! Is find_peaks() library code?

Comment: scipy library. ```from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths, find_peaks_cwt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema```

Comment: You can specify a minimal value for the peak width in `find_peaks()`, which should help you. Then, what you call `peaks` is actually a matter of perspective ? Is it the maximal values ? Local maxima (then what is local ?) etc ...

Comment: yes maximal values, can you please show an example with test ? I posted everything

Comment: @Liris Actually width didn't help much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replacing the line:

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(env > 0.1, height= 0.51)
```

by

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(env, height = 0.1, width = 4)
```

gives

[image]

I suggest that you take time reading the documentation of funtion you use. Foe example, setting `height = 0.51` here is nonsense as height is:

> Required height of peaks. Either a number, None, an array matching x
>   or a 2-element sequence of the former. The first element is always
>   interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied, as the maximal
>   required height.

However, keep in mind that it is really difficult to make a reliable 'calibration' of functions that find peaks if you have signals that are too different. For example, the parameter width is set to 4 here, but I suggest you play with all the parameters to see what they do.

Finally, it is always a matter of taste. The first pic at the left is a double one. How to you know that the maximal value is actually what you want ? Finding reliable peaks in a signal is tricky.